# Can't update table 'comment' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

Now there is a database table called comments. Comments can be sub-comments of articles, files or comments. `father_table`indicates to which category this comment is attached.`father_id` indicates the id of article,file or comment.

```sql
create table comment(
    id int(11) not null auto_increment,
    user_id int(11) not null ,
    father_id int(11) not null ,
    father_table enum('file','article','comment') not null ,
    create_date timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    content text not null ,
    primary key (id),
    foreign key (user_id) references user (id) on delete cascade
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

I want to delete all sub-comments of this comment after deleting each comment.So I wrote a trigger.

```sql
create trigger foreign_key_cascade_delete_comment
    after delete on comment
    for each row begin
    delete from comment where father_table='comment' and father_id=OLD.id;
    delete from attitude where father_table='comment' and father_id=OLD.id;
    delete from collect where father_table='comment' and father_id=OLD.id;
end;
```

Then,I delete a record from `article` table and `file` table and it works well.
But when I delet a record from `comment` it goes wrong.The error message is here.

```
[HY000][1442] Can't update table 'comment' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

I want to know how to make sure that all sub-comments are deleted where one comment is deleted.
How to use triggers to achieve this goal?(The database is MySql 8)

Comment: 'How to use triggers to achieve this goal' - There is no way to use trigger on comment to do this..

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this constraint？

Comment: Consider using a procedure and wrapping the deletes in a transaction.